# MultipleLines custom field in VSO does not appear in Power BI report's dataset

Tags: odata, azure-devops, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I referred the [Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/analytics/access-analytics-power-bi) to import the data from my VSO into a Power BI report.
I'm able to view all the Fields data related to a Work item (ex: title, assigned to, state) in 'WorkItems' table.
I'm also able to view the Custom fields data as shown below:
[image: Custom Fields - in report]

All the above custom fields in VSO are of type, text(single line), drop down, date etc.

But, i'm unable to find all those custom fields, which are of type "Text (multiple lines)", the fields in VSO which are rich text editors/html type.
[image]

How can i get those field values ? Is it not currently supported ?

Comment: I also tried with the Power BI Data Connector and Power BI Content Pack. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior since we don't support Long Text Fields at this time. You can pull the field via [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items) and then combine them with Analytics Data set in Power BI.

Check this link for reference: [Querying the VSTS Work Items API directly from Power BI](https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/07/querying-the-vsts-work-items-api-directly-from-power-bi/).

Comment: This worked!! But, now i have this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570590/power-bi-service-refresh-failure-on-using-vso-api) issue.